# How to turn off internet connection, bluetooth and WIFI programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to turn off  internet connection, bluetooth and WIFI programmatically xcode.

Comment: You want to off internet connection, bluetooth and WIFI of device  programmatically?

Comment: yes i want cellular data turn on / off from my app.

Comment: This seems like a valid question, and not too broad. The fact that the answer is "you can't do that" doesn't mean the question is invalid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to change global system settings like that.

Answer (score 1):

Legally there is no way to do it. Even somehow if you are manage to do it, Apple will reject your app while submitting to AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available to control cellular data,wi-fi,bluetooth within in an app , User have to go to settings to enable or disable cellular data,wi-fi and bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in iOS unless you jailbroke your device. Apple is not allowing any apps developer to access wifi/bluetooth. You can only check wifi/tooth is connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using the iOS application. Apple not allowing it.